# Insertar fecha y hora en sql server con entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, entity-framework-6

tengo un insert en entity framework de la siguiente manera

```
 Contacto a = this.ToEntity();
                contexto.Contactos.Add(a);
                a.FechaAlta = DateTime.Today.Date;
                a.Icono = "red.png";
                DateTime hoy = DateTime.Today.Date;
                a.Oculto = false;           
                a.FechaContacto = hoy;                   
                contexto.SaveChanges();
                return true;
```

El tema es que siempre guarda fechas de la forma 2019-04-04 00:00:00.000
y no guarda la hora, y la necesito, el campo lo tengo declarado asi:

```
 public DateTime? FechaContacto { get; set; }
```

Alguien sabe que sucede?  tanto en FechaAlta como en FechaContacto no guarda la hora... gracias

Comment: Cuando haces `DateTime.Today` Today devuelve la fecha actual con las horas en `00:00:00` y la propiedad `Date` que llamas despues tambien devuelve la fecha sin hora. Lo que debes utilizar es `DateTime.Now`.

Comment: Buenisimo, si era eso, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para persistir la fecha y hora debes usar

```
DateTime hoy = DateTime.Now;
```

de esta forma tendras ambos datos

Al usar el `Date` solo estas tomando la fecha dejando la hora con un valor estandar

[DateTime.Now Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.datetime.now?view=netframework-4.7.2)